# Python: Numpy accumulated list not seperated by commas

Tags: python, list, numpy, accumulate

Simple example: I got a list called 'mylist' and I want to accumulate the numbers inside and save them into a new list called 'mylist_accum'.

```
import numpy

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
print mylist

mylist_accum = numpy.add.accumulate(mylist)
print mylist_accum
```

My prints look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[ 1  3  6 10 15]
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

I need my accumulated listelements to be seperated by commas. Otherwise Matplotlib cant work with them.

Comment: Convert to list with `.tolist()` and then print?

Comment: Matplotlib handles numpy arrays (which your `mylist_accum` is) just fine. What makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just printing, matplotlib could handle with the numpy.arrays easy:

```
In [77]: type(mylist_accum)
Out[77]: numpy.ndarray
```

If you want to see with commas you could use [.tolist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method of the numpy.array:

```
In [75]: mylist_accum.tolist()
Out[75]: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Or convert it to usual list:

```
In [74]: list(mylist_accum)
Out[74]: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: `list()` does not handle 2d (or higher nd) arrays well.  `tolist()` is more consistent.